# execute a windows cmd line from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, cmd

I'm fairly new to the oracle environment (but am extremely familiar with SQL Server) and am trying to figure out how to launh a windows CMD line at the end of my PL/SQL procedure. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: is there a reason you want to launch the command prompt from the PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: yes, the oracle PL/SQL returns either true or false for outage notification. If it is true, a BAT file needs to run on the report server to send out the appropriate information. I can use the Psexec function (tested already) to launch the BAT file on the remote server. I just can't figure out how to launch this CMD: psexec \\servername -p password -u userID c:\Autobatch\ClientJobSender.exe http://reportserver.net:80/automation/JobExecutor.asmx c:\AutoBatch\criticalevent.xml

Comment: the only way I can think of, is to use [Java to call the command](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:x2r-071B9lkJ:www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf+&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgUI4Xlx4ycS5_DHBttuxXvtqIMmr6hCXj-LXonqoM3QMqoRtfwJ-3zrcS5zFnoBKrLUxqXNx4Z4zrTZAUuBZ_8k1DceFTzaoU1aCxd6ddgIzd5HArsIyFqqfCdbykim7WKMgCb&sig=AHIEtbTNH6cgLhBK75lRE3x47yFFxUFvWg). Otherwise, have the procedure print the result & process it - [like so](http://serverfault.com/questions/159755/sql-pl-sql-sqlplus-how)

Answer (score 3):

DBMS_Scheduler can run a .bat file. See "job_type" and "job_action" in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_sched.htm

Equally well, Oracle can send an email of course: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_mail.htm#i1001258